# Allow both authenticated and unauthenticated users access a django rest view with token authentication decorator

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working with django rest, I however have an issue in one of my views because, i want to allow both authenticated users and unauthenticated users access the view then check if the user is authenticated then there are some special events to be done by the celery tasks, however, whenever i add the decorator for the authentication_classes, unauthenticated users can no longer visit the page even after setting the permission_classes to allow all
simply my code is here, hope someone can know what i need to add or remove

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
def item_details(request, pk): 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #here some tasks
```

the main issue is that it seams that TokenAuthentication just nullify AllowAny and takes over the checking of the permisssion class
or is there something am doing wrong?

Comment: Set the permission_classes decorator below the authentication_classes decorator

Comment: I just tried this, not helping though...

Comment: what makes you see that it's not working? afaik this should work, so I'm wondering what happens exactly.

Comment: ````Unauthorized: /home/details/5/
HTTP GET /home/details/5/ 401 [0.09, 192.168.0.147:49244]```` this is error I get if i try accessing page with unauthenticated user

Comment: Weird, there's nothing in the code you're showing that would produce this. Can't reproduce. And actually the order doesn't matter, all the decorators do is set the attribute on the function. You'll have to show more code, or use a debugger to step through figuring out where the 401 is raised.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the authenticate method of TokenAuthentication

**myauth.py**

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class TokenAuthenticationSafe(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        try:
            return super().authenticate(request=request)
        except:
            return None
```

**views.py**

```
from myauth import TokenAuthenticationSafe

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthenticationSafe])
def item_details(request, pk): 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #here some tasks
```