# Allow both authenticated and anonymous user access to a view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following in *settings.py*:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%c",
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

I am trying to have a view that does different things for authenticated and anonymous (guest) users:

```py
class CourseListView(generics.ListAPIView):
   permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]

   def list(self, request, format=None):
      user = request.user
      realUserFlag = not user.is_anonymous
      ...
```

This works as expected for authenticated users, but returns Unauthorized (401) error for anonymous ones. What am I missing?

P.S. A variation on this topic with decorators appears [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997792/allow-both-authenticated-and-unauthenticated-users-access-a-django-rest-view-wit), but does not seem to have a good answer.

Comment: If you remove `permission_classes`  you should be able to access it without any permissions

Comment: Your code should work, can you share the serializer, more of the view, and your urls.py, maybe something else is happening in one of those places.

Comment: @mousetail Nope, it does not work.

Comment: @Daniel I don't see how any of that can be relevant. An invocation of the view is attempted, so the urls are fine. The rest of the `list` method seems to be irrelevant, because the method does not get invoked...

Comment: it could *appear* that the view is being invoked, but perhaps something else is wired up differently, your code, as you've shared it, should achieve what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: what happens if you remove the permission class from your settings.py file? or setting "allow any" from there?

Comment: @Daniel This would break all the other views based on token authentication... So no, I want that default.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked is to define a separate class for each kind of user. The original class in the question becomes the base class for the two classes, only that the base class does not derive from any base class:

```py
class CourseListViewBase():
   def list(self, request, format=None):
      # as before

class CourseListView(CourseListViewBase, generics.ListAPIView):
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

class CourseListViewGuest(CourseListViewBase, generics.ListAPIView):
   permission_classes = []
   authentication_classes = []
```

Note that the order of base classes is important.